# vba click a website button

Tags: html, excel, vba, button, web-scraping

I have some code that used to work fine, but for some reason it has stopped selecting the tab that says "your leagues".
The code pulls live football scores into excel.
The only bit I need help with is where I need to navigate from all games to your leagues (the code does not recognize the button and so is not clicking it).  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
 'Define Variables
        url = "http://www.futbol24.com/Live/livenow/"


    'Open url
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.Navigate url
        frmbusy.lbstatus.AddItem "Navigating to Web Page"
        busywait

    'Navigate from ALL Games to Your Leagues
        Set tagname = ie.Document.getelementsbytagname("*")

        For z = 0 To tagname.Length - 1
           If tagname(z).ID = "f24com_i18n_btnChooseLeague_your" Then
                tagname(z).Click
                busywait
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Please examine the source HTML of this page, and you will find that the ID `f24com_btnChooseLeague_your` does not exist.

Comment: Nor is there a tab which says "Your leagues" (at least not when I view it, perhaps it is different if you log in...)  Sometimes websites change the way they are built, and you need to modify your code when that happens.

Comment: Apologies.  I've updated the tag name: "f24com_i18n_btnChooseLeague_your" but it still does not click it.  Thanks.

Comment: Click is clearly not an event that is *doing* anything for this control. You may want to look in to using the Selenium wrapper to automate IE/Firefox/Chrome, in my experience it's more reliable than trying to bluntly automate IE directly.  Also, consider using `ie.Document.getElementByID("f24com_i18n_btnChooseLeague_your")` if your version of IE supports that method, then you won't need the `z` loop as that will directly handle the element. You may need to manipulate the parent element somehow but i can't really tell for sure.

Comment: Also, if you can upload screenshot to imgur.com and indicate *where* this control or its parent are located on the page, I can't really find it so that makes it difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I've uploaded the image as requested [link](http://imgur.com/SZ01btx)

Comment: When I navigate to that page, I do not see a tab for "Your Leagues", instead, I see "Choose Leagues". Do you need to be logged in to see "Your Leagues"? If so, I can't really help with that...

Comment: Sorry.  I understand now.  If it is the first time you visit, just click a couple of leagues and at the bottom check the box 'remember my leagues' and then click ok.  You will then seen the screen above.  In future visits it will go straight to the screen.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see it but it still has the id property of "f24com_btnChooseLeague_choose" and I am able to click it with `Set tagname = ie.Document.getElementByID("f24com_btnChooseLeague_choose")` and then `tagname.click` which pops up the additional screen...

Comment: I'm sorry, this football website is sh!t and I'm not able to assist you with this specific task any further.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming the button with the id exists on the page, it must be a timing issue. First check that The id is correct. Then try code which gets an existing open and navigated page and just get the button and click it. In my experience the button can be there and you can get a reference to it but it's not ready for a click. If my suggested test works then we can work on waiting longer or setting up an event handler on the button to know it was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a querySelector to target

```
#f24com_btnChooseLeague_choose > a > span
```

This is the `span` tag within an `a` tag with element with id `#f24com_btnChooseLeague_choose`

You can shorten this simply to `#f24com_btnChooseLeague_choose > a`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClickChooseLeagues()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.futbol24.com/Live/livenow/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("#f24com_btnChooseLeague_choose > a").Click

        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```